# Google Data Studio report performance

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I am currently setting up Google Analytics to track report performance so how many views by a client, how many sessions, session length, etc?

However, it seems that we can only create this by adding the GA ID to every report individually which could take forever. Has anyone tried to do this and if so were you able to find a way to add it to every report at one time or is it not possible?

Thanks,
Shiel.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the GA ID seems to be the way to go.  AFAIK, there is no *supported* way to automate this task.

I have hundreds of reports in Data Studio, and I don't think it is a very difficult task.  Particularly, add the GA ID is the first thing I always do when I create a new dashboard.

Even if you didn't add it yet and you have a huge number of reports to add the GA ID in your backlog, keep in mind that it is a task you'll need to do once.

However, if you *really* need to automate this, you can probably create a macro to do this automatically with [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/), but you need to evaluate if it worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks Diego. It looks like this is the only option so we will just have to make it standard practice moving forward. Thanks for your help